# Convert JavaScript into C# - obfuscation

Tags: javascript, c#

i have the below Javascript code i need to convert to C#

```
function obfuscateApiKey(timestamp, key) {
    var high = timestamp.substring(timestamp.length - 6);
    var low = (parseInt(high) >> 1).toString();
    var apiKey = "";


    while (low.length < 6) {
        low = "0" + low;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < high.length; i++) {
        apiKey += key.charAt(parseInt(high.charAt(i)));
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < low.length; j++) {
        apiKey += key.charAt(parseInt(low.charAt(j)) + 2);
    }
        console.log(apiKey)
    return apiKey;
}
```

I have started the conversion below in C# but i am stuck at converting

```
apiKey += key.charAt(parseInt(high.charAt(i)));
```

```
var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
var high = timestamp.Substring(timestamp.Length - 6);
var low = (Int32.Parse(high) >>1).ToString();
while (low.Length < 6)
{
    low = "0" + low;
}
for (var i = 0; i < high.Length; i++)
{
    char ch = (int.Parse(high)[i]); //Getting stuck here! < this is incorrect.
}
```

Comment: It should simply be `char ch = high[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

you got it wrong at `(high)[i]` try `high[i]` you are converting char to int and then assign it to char.

```
var apiKey = "";
var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
var high = timestamp.Substring(timestamp.Length - 6);
var low = (Int32.Parse(high) >>1).ToString();
while (low.Length < 6)
{
    low = "0" + low;
}
for (var i = 0; i < high.Length; i++)
{
    apiKey += high[i]; 
}
```

and for your comment `char ch = low[j] + 2`

```
apiKey  += (Convert.ToInt32(low[j]) + 2).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks Ameya, However i still have an issue when adding the below char ch = high[i]; - No issue however i need the below apiKey += char ch = high[i]; (with this i get "invalid expression term 'char'") i also get the below error when entering char ch = low[j] + 2; "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"